# i am using flutter_flavorizr: ^2.1.6 package i want to know how can i update my app icon

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my config file please help in pubspec.yaml file I have added the proper path for my icons and still don't have any clue how to generate icons.

> flavors:
> iBEProd:
> app:
> name: "iBreastExam"
> android:
> applicationId: ...
> firebase:
> config: ".android/prod/google-services.json"
> ios:
> bundleId: ...
> iBEDev:
> app:
> name: "iBE Dev"
> android:
> applicationId: ...
> firebase:
> config: ...
> ios:
> bundleId: ...
> cervaicalProd:
> app:
> name: "Cervaical"
> android: "assets/icons/cervaical_icon.png"
> ios: "assets/icons/cervaical_icon.png"
> android:
> applicationId: ...
> firebase:
> config: ".android/prod/google-services.json"
> ios:
> bundleId: ...
> cervaicalDev:
> app:
> name: "Cervaical Dev"
> android: "assets/icons/cervaical_icon.png"
> ios: "assets/icons/cervaical_icon.png"
> android:
> applicationId: ...
> firebase:
> config: ".android/dev/google-services.json"
> ios:
> bundleId: ...

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation. to set separate app icon for each flavor, you can simply define an `icon` attribute for each flavor type for both android and ios.

Example:

```
flavors:
    development:
      app:
        name: "Development Flavor"

      android:
        applicationId: "com.dev.flavorsdemo"
        icon: "assets/path-to-your-icon"


      ios:
        bundleId: "com.dev.flavorsdemo"
        buildSettings:
          # Development Team is visible in the apple developer portal 
          DEVELOPMENT_TEAM: YOURDEVTEAMID 
          PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER: "Dev-ProvisioningProfile"
        icon: "assets/path-to-your-icon"
```

For detailed documentation, [GO HERE](https://pierre-dev.hashnode.dev/get-the-best-out-of-flutter-flavors-with-flutterflavorizr#heading-demo-app)